# LAN address with FQDN, is there anyway to prevent resolution outside the LAN?

Tags: domain-name-system, local-area-network

I understand that it is possible to add a DNS A record that points to a local network IP address. However, if someone tries to reach it from another LAN it would return the same IP, but in that case it would point to another computer.

Is there any way to prevent this? So that the DNS will only resolve if the request is made from a specific network?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, these are called "views" in BIND. Other DNS software have similar functionality.